# How to get the result of a php function from an ajax-jquery request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is an ajax-jquery request to call a PHP function from my local file.

How can I get the result of 'data: { functionname: 'getIntervenant', arguments: [] }' in javascript?

```
jQuery.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'http://localhost:8012/extension-Oasis/php/getIntervenant.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: { functionname: 'getIntervenant', arguments: [] },

          success:    function (obj, textstatus) {
                    if( !('error' in obj) ) yourVariable = obj.result;
                    else  console.log(obj.error);
         }
});
```

this my the php function:

```
function getIntervenant(){

    $CI = 'EDIFICE';

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT ID,Nom FROM intervenant WHERE nextAffect='x' and CI=:ci");
    $stmt->bindParam(":ci",$CI);
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)){
      $id = $row[0];
      $name = $row[1];
    }
    return $name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `return` use `echo` like :

```
echo $name;
```

In the js part you will receive the result like :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://localhost:8012/extension-Oasis/php/getIntervenant.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { functionname: 'getIntervenant', arguments: [] },
).done(function( name ) {
    console.log(name);
});
```

Comment: how do I get it from javascript